# Converting plain text to hyperlink in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a use case where I need to identify phone numbers in a string and convert them to a clickable link. Using an external library is out of scope currently.

Here is what I've done so far:

String: "This is my phone number - 1234567890"
I can extract 1234567890 as a phone number using a regex pattern.

I now want to replace it in the original string, so this is what I did:

```
const string = "This is my phone number - 1234567890"
const number = "1234567890"
const newString = '<a href="#">' + number + '</a>'
number = number.replace(number, newString);
```

When I do this, instead of getting the phone number as a hyperlink, my output is like this:

```
This is my phone number - <a href="#">1234567890</a>
```

If I create my newString without quotes, like this

```
const newString = <a href="#">number</a>
```

my output is like this:

```
This is my phone number - [object Object]
```

How do I make this a clickable link?

Comment: It's not clear how you're getting your output. Are you putting `number` into a JSX return value somewhere? Please show that code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to highlight matches within a string with JSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57597563/how-to-highlight-matches-within-a-string-with-jsx)

Comment: While the duplicate candidate focuses on highlighting words, the concept is exactly the same to replace part of a string and render valid JSX without `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String as html in reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23602974/string-as-html-in-reactjs)

Comment: Also, maybe just `const newString = <>This is my phone number - <a href="#">{number}</a></>;`?

Comment: Working example below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to replace to wrap the phone numbers with links, and then use [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](http://dangerouslySetInnerHTML) to add to React components.

**Note:** It's called `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` because you open yourself to XSS attacks from user generated content. You should [sanitise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38663751/how-to-safely-render-html-in-react/38663813#38663813) the strings first.

```js
const Linkify = ({ text, pattern, formatter }) => {
  const __html = text.replace(pattern, formatter);

  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html }} />;
};

const text = 'This is my phone number - 1234567890';
const pattern = /\d+/g;
const formatter = str => `<a href="#${str}">${str}</a>`;

ReactDOM.render(
  <Linkify text={text} pattern={pattern} formatter={formatter} />,
  root
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Without using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` the main problem is breaking the string into links/non links strings. This can be done by using the code in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45502134/5157454). I've updated the code to mark string as matches, so you can format them accordingly.

```js
const Linkify = ({ text, pattern, formatter }) => {
  const arr = getSegments(pattern, text);

  return arr.map(formatter);
};

const text = 'This is my phone number - 1234567890, and his is 34234123142';
const pattern = /\d+/g;
const formatter = ({ text, match }) => match ? <a href={`#${text}`}>{text}</a> : text;

ReactDOM.render(
  <Linkify text={text} pattern={pattern} formatter={formatter} />,
  root
);

function getSegments(rex, str) {
  const segments = [];
  let lastIndex = 0;
  let match;
  rex.lastIndex = 0; // In case there's a dangling previous search
  while (match = rex.exec(str)) {
    if (match.index > lastIndex) {
      segments.push({ text: str.substring(lastIndex, match.index) });
    }
    segments.push({ text: match[0], match: true });
    lastIndex = match.index + match[0].length;
  }
  if (lastIndex < str.length) {
    segments.push({ text: str.substring(lastIndex) });
  }
  return segments;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation @OriDrori! this was essentially what I was attempting to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really want to set a 'string' to `const newString`, I would call this more an element. You can do it like this:

```
const phoneEl = (
  <a href="#">
    {number}
  </a>
);
```

Where `number` is the phone number stored in a variable called `number`.

Then you would write:

```
<p>My phone number is - {phoneEl}</p>
```

I'd also suggest

```
<href={`tel:${number}`}>
```

if you wanted people to be able to click the link and dial.

Comment: This is the best answer which takes React's best practices into account. Only missing the brackets: ```href={`tel:${number}`}``` (upvoted anyway)

Comment: @EmileBergeron yeah, oversight haha, I've fixed it. Not sure why it's been downvoted with no comment :/

Answer (score -1):

```js
const string = document.querySelector("body");
const text = string.innerText;

const textArr = text.split(" ").map(item => {
  if(item.match(/^[\+]?[(]?[0-9]{3}[)]?[-\s\.]?[0-9]{3}[-\s\.]?[0-9]{4,6}$/im)){
    item = `<a href="tel:${item}">${item}</a>`;
  }
  return item;
});

const newText = textArr.join(" ");

console.log({ newText })

string.innerHtml = newText;
```

```html
<p class="body">
  This is my phone number - 555-555-5555
</p>
```

Comment: This is a React question, manipulating the DOM directly is a bad practice.

Comment: Ahhh.  Didn't see the reactjs tag.  Only saw javascript in the title.